# Why Database is Locked while inserting data in sqlite in IOS?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

Why is I'm getting database is locked while inserting data in sqlite? I already open and close my all my database code? I have this code:

```
-(void)insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data: (NSString *)empID ProdId: (NSString *)prodId ProdName: (NSString *)prodName  GenName: (NSString *)genName ComputeType: (NSString *)computeType UOM: (NSString *)uom ListPrice: (NSString *)listPrice UOMQty: (NSString *)uomqty{

    const char *query = "insert into tbl_selectItem_data (femployeeid,fproductid,fname,fgeneric_name,fcompute_type,fuom,flist_price,fuomqty) values (?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &(_database)) == SQLITE_OK) {
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(_database, query, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {

            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [empID UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [prodId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [prodName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [genName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 5, [computeType UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 6, [uom UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 7, [listPrice UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 8, [uomqty UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

            if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE){
                NSLog(@"Insert Successful");
                sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
            }else{
                NSLog(@"insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
            }
        }
    }

    sqlite3_close(_database);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling this method in loop?

Comment: No I'm calling that method once. When I click the add button

Comment: can you print `sqlite3_errmsg`, and ad where you call tis method.'

Comment: I already print that slite3_errmsg and it returns me a value of database is locked

Comment: Check have you open database for other operation? any other operation read ?

Comment: I open and I closed all the operation in database.

Answer (score 1):

First off all... try to 'finalize" your statement even if there are errors... so your method:

```
if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Insert Successful");
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
        }else{
            NSLog(@"insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        }
    }
}
sqlite3_close(_database);
```

is better to be:

```
if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_DONE){
            NSLog(@"Insert Successful");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"insertDataIn_tbl_selectItem_data error: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(_database));
        }
    }
 sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}

sqlite3_close(_database);
```

The second...

you can try to use `sqlite3_open_v2` instead `sqlite3_open`  More about that here: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

So... instead:

```
if (sqlite3_open([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &(_database)) == SQLITE_OK) {...}
```

will be: `if (sqlite3_open_v2([sqLiteDb UTF8String], &(_database), SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {....}`